# macOS Sierra 10.12.2 root cannot write in /usr/sbin

Tags: macos, terminal, permissions, root

Can anyone shed some light why?

```
# whoami
root

# ls -ld /usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x  246 root  wheel  8364 Jan  3 14:36 /usr/sbin

# pwd
/

# touch test-file
# ls -ltr test-file
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  0 Jan 10 00:27 test-file

# cp test-file /usr/sbin
cp: /usr/sbin/test-file: Operation not permitted

# ls -ld@ /usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x  246 root  wheel  8364 Jan  3 14:36 /usr/sbin
```

Comment: Does OSX have the `chattr` command? If it does, can you check if the directory is set to inpermutable.

Comment: Here is the [apple.stackexchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11) post on how to _disable_ this **System Integrity Protection**, if that is why you are asking.

Comment: Hennes, the OS X doesn't have the chattr command, I believe the ls -ld@ is the equivalent. which I used - shows no special attributes.

Comment: user4556274, thank you for that link !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is macOS **System Integrity Protection** (SIP) which prevents even root from changing things in `/System`, `/usr`, `/bin`, `/sbin` and pre-installed Apps.

An exception in `/usr` is that `/usr/local` can be written.

The Apple support document about this is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204899)